# How do I carry a variable's value out of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So I am writing code for a small game and have gotten everything to work except that the health bar does not decrease. The health decreases and the game ends when health reaches zero, but the bar stays at full.

The part of code that draws the rectangle is outside of the function where the health decreases. So I figured that what I need to do is have the health variable be the same outside of the function as it is inside. How would I do this?

(Note: I've tried bringing the part of code that draws the rectangle inside the function but that didn't change anything.)

Comment: can you please provide your code.

Comment: Try researching "Variable Scope in Javascript" or something similar.

Comment: The code for drawing the rectangle looks like this:
health = width + health;
context.rect(10, 15, health, 15);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill();

Comment: @Feathercrown you mean Java.

Comment: I should mention I'm using a java script that is being run in html.

Comment: @DevinShawHuffman `Javascript` is totally unrelated to`java`

Comment: @ostrichofevil Ow, my sense of correctness. It hurts. ;)

Comment: @Feathercrown was confused by the tag

Comment: Make your variable Class global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback function call that will connect the two function. Alternatives include observers to tell you if some global state object has changed. If you could provide some code samples it will be much easier to provide assistance.